# Is there a way to get variable's name in java

Tags: java

```
String getName(Object o)
{
  //TODO
}
String object = "i want to get "object" not these words"
getName(object);
```

Is it possible the method return "object"? thx

Comment: Not any variable, only class fields and, through many hardships, parameter names.

Comment: Why? There's probably a better way to accomplish whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: We're confronting another case of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/182862). Please describe your real problem instead of the proposed solution you think it could do

Comment: You know what the variable name is when writing the source. Just use that.

Comment: Also, remember a variable only holds a reference to an object. When you pass it to a method like `getName()` you are passing a copy of the value of the reference, so the variable name is lost.

Comment: If you preserve local variable names when compiling, you can retrieve them using the debugging API. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228770/java-access-to-local-variable-names).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to get the name of a local variable used to pass a value to a method.

You may be able to do some kind of static source code analysis, but at runtime the stack does not include information such as this.